# Actors responsible for persisting the data they will use?

Tags: scala, architecture, persistence, akka, actor

I am creating a distributed system with many actors using akka/scala. Most of the "worker" actors will be performing essentially the same operation on a different subset of a large set of data. Instead of storing the data in a common database and distributing it to the worker actors when the computation is needed, I was thinking about dividing the data up between the worker actors as it is created and making each worker responsible for persisting the data it will eventually operate on.

Is this a common architecture and under what circumstances would it make sense? What are the downsides to creating an architecture in which each agent is responsible for persisting the data it will work on?

Comment: Are all workers running on the same node or it will be remote actors running on different nodes?

Comment: You are you using [agents](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.2/scala/agents.html), or is it actors you mean.

Comment: @alois cochard yes, I expect they will be on different nodes.

Comment: @patrik nordwall I am not sure yet, but I meant to say actors.  Thanks for the reference.  I am not familiar will all of the terminology/concepts yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a typical divide and conquer approach.

The thing to keep in mind when thinking about letting workers storing the processed data is that this process is typically IO bound. Depending of the way you store data, you might not get any gain doing so.

If you are using remote actors, and storing data one the local disk of the node where the worker is executed, that's fine. Because IO is bound when writing to the harddrive which can be distributed in the cluster. If all the workers where running on the same node, you won't get any gain doing that, because the bottleneck would be writing to the disk.

Hope that help.